# Flex order not working in mozzila firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

I have bootstrap card, and i'm trying to change ***order*** position of image `card-img-top` from bottom to top, whit media query. Its working in chrome, edge, opera, vivaldi, but ***flex order*** doesn't seems to be working in mozila firefox. What could cause this problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="card card-second" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Heading</h5>
                    <img src="img/test-image.png" class="rectangle">
                    <p class="card-text rounded-card">Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <img class="card-img-top img-center" src="img/image-frame.png" alt="Card image cap">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .card-second .card-body .card-img-top{
        -webkit-order: -1;
        order: -1;
        display: -webkit-box;      
        display: -moz-box;         
        display: -ms-flexbox;      
        display: -webkit-flex;     
        display: flex;
    }
```

*Last time I checked, firefox supports flex order, but seems not working.*

> How it looks in firefox: http://prntscr.com/icq5w8
>
> How it looks in other browsers: http://prntscr.com/icq6dm

Comment: share your full css code .. try to create a working snippet to be able to reproduce the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wvffx9dc/ This is how its now displayed in firefox

Comment: This is how it should be displayed in firefox whit working order https://jsfiddle.net/wvffx9dc/1/

Comment: Is maybe any other way to change order of items inside container whit media query?

Comment: can you share the full code :) with boststrap included .. we need to see it working on chrome and not FF. We need to see the issue

Comment: I added image links

Comment: we need code :) we need to reproduce your issue to help you

Comment: Firefox deleted, problem solved :)

Comment: You are confusing. everything always works in `Firefox` and *sometimes* works in other browsers. Also, you did not specify the **version**. also, avoid using **negative** `order` values.

Comment: what you mean by firefox deleted ?

Comment: I unistalled firefox, i'm not gonna use it and i'm gonna pretend like doesn't exist. Feel bad for firefox users, guess they will have to switch to better alternatives.

Comment: Well, if you use Flexbox's properties properly it will work, which you didn't. Read up on the difference between a flex container and a flex item, and you'll find the mistake you made. And btw, it will be you who will suffer more when your Firefox users will stop visiting your site.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want only .card-img-top to be at top in all browsers you only need to set as flex the img container like this.

i have tested it in mozilla and it works as expected.

```css
  .card-body{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card-img-top{
   order: -1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="card card-second" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Heading</h5>
           <img src="https://eter22.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/homero_simpson.jpg" class="rectangle">
           <p class="card-text rounded-card">Lorem ipsum</p>
           <img class="card-img-top img-center" src="http://sonarfm.cl/sonarfm/site/artic/20160217/imag/foto_0000001120160217172059.png" alt="Card image cap">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This. Give flex property to direct parent element and then order property to direct child element

```
.card-second .card-body{
   display: -webkit-box;      
   display: -moz-box;         
   display: -ms-flexbox;      
   display: -webkit-flex;     
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.card-second .card-body .card-img-top{
  order:-1;
}
```